# top bar style for ask ubuntu

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, windows

The Top bar for Ask Ubuntu (and Meta) doesn't seem to have enough space from the top of the window area. When a notification (badge, welcome/faq) etc appears, it is very close to the text. This seems different to all the other SE sites...The other sites have it nicely aligned with the Search box.

Personally, the Ask Ubuntu site is one of the best styled sites of all of them, just needs this bit fixed up. Here's the Chrome user agent in case it's not like this for everyone...

Google Chrome   9.0.597.107 (Official Build 75357)
WebKit  534.13
V8  2.5.9.15
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.107 Safari/534.13

Here are the screenshots of how it looks...
[image: Main Ask Ubuntu Site]

[image: Meta Site]

[image: SO top bar]

**EDIT**
Added in a screenshot of the same problem happening for me in IE8 on Windows XP
[image: ie8 in vm showing error]

Comment: what browser and OS are you using? It doesn't look like that at all for me, in fact, it looks quite different.. I suspect fonts but the line-height seems really off.

Comment: Using Windows 7 Pro with Google Chrome (user agent string is in the question)

Comment: It also looks the same as my screenshots using Firefox 4.0b12

Comment: Hmmm, just got the Firefox 4.0...there you go. still a problem in it. Also a problem in Safari 5.0.3 and IE8. A font issues makes sense...although I haven't done anything specific...so I can only assume others will get this as well.

Comment: technically, using Windows on this site may take away from it being an issue ;)

Comment: @Jeff could it be that the Ubuntu font family isn't being respected on Windows - if so could it be fixed with [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Ubuntu&subset=latin)?

Comment: Also confirmed that my machine has the ubuntu font installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your fonts, in my opinion.

I am also on Windows 7 with Google Chrome and it looks like this, even *after* [installing the Ubuntu fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Ubuntu&subset=latin#download):

[image]

Here's a new account I just created without the diamond (which could, it is true, affect height):

[image]

So it is a few pixels higher for sure *with this crazy Ubuntu font on Windows only.*

That's kind of an exceptional case..

Comment: It displays the same for me (as in not quite right) on my laptop as well (also Windows 7 Pro). However, I have noticed that the effect is "lessened" when you have a badge icon. I presume because the badge images create more space around them...Will try the site out on some other machines to see what happens.

Comment: reproduced on windows XP pro using IE8...I appreciate that it could be my fonts though...but being able to just go to the site on various machines and see the problem for me suggests it isn't "just me"

Comment: @david crap you might be right-- that diamond could affect it.